# How to add hyper link text to TextConsoleViewer?

Tags: java, swt, jface

In my application i have a dialog where i am putting a text console viewer.On text console viewer there is some text .Can i make some of the text as hyperlink.Any pointer on this is appreciated.

Code:

```
console = new MessageConsole("Try", null, false);

outputStream = console.newMessageStream();

Composite viewerParent = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);

GridLayout layout2 = new GridLayout();
layout2.marginBottom = layout2.marginHeight = layout2.marginLeft = layout2.marginRight = layout2.marginTop = layout2.marginWidth = 1;

viewerParent.setLayout(layout2);
viewerParent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

viewer = new TextConsoleViewer(viewerParent, console);
viewer.setEditable(false);

viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Comment: What text console viewer are you talking about? Eclipse's TextConsoleViewer? Swing's JTextArea/JEditorPane?

Comment: I tagged it as swt it means that it is from swt not from swing.. am i ryt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here an example of program how to how to hypertext..
 the code is large so i can't post it here so i posting the link please refer this:

```
http://www.java2v.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/ui/org/eclipse/ui/console/TextConsoleViewer.java.htm
```

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"www.java2v.com’s server IP address could not be found."*